# How do I execute a custom code function only once on a reporting services report?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I need to execute a custom code function when the report first loads, and I need it to only run once.  Where do I put it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how the best way to do this is. I don't think you get any events to hook in to, but you could fudge it. For example, have the header call a function to set the title, and as a by-product call your custom code function once:

```
Public Dim ReportTitle As String = ""

Public Function GetTitleAndDoSomethingElse As String
    If (ReportTitle = "") Then
        ReportTitle = "My Report Title"
        ' Do your stuff that runs once here
    End If
    Return ReportTitle
End Function
```

Then in your report header have a text box that is set to:

```
=Code.GetTitleAndDoSomethingElse
```

Ugly, but should do the trick.

Comment: I'm doing basically the same thing but in a field on the chart.  I'll accept your answer, and maybe someone will come along later with the proper way to run code once.

Answer (score 0):

From the menu bar select Report then Report Properties. In the pop up select the Code tab. Write your code in there.

Comment: I have my code in a function in the code tab - where do I call it from?  I can't find the onLoad event or similar.

Comment: @NathanDeWitt Have a textbox where you want to call this function and call this function in the expression window

Comment: This answer assumes a lot.  It assumes you want to define an expression that can be used by a textbox.  The OP specifically asked about a function that is invoked once on Load and preferably an example.  This answer does not address the OP question.